# Increase a string with number by 1 with pattern

Tags: linux, unix

I would like to know the UNIX command that could increase a string or number by 1 which find in a file, for example:

```
String0001
2222220001
233333-7777-0001-33335
```

Say, search for 0001 and replace it with 0002 in the file after command is called. And, the increments shall like 0001,0002,...,0010,...0011,etc when each time is called.

Comment: You have to know what you like to do. Find the sequence 0000 or any sequence of digits. 233333-7777-0001-33335 could be increased at 4 levels, how to decide which? By length? There are two of length 4.

Comment: I just wanted to increase 0001 by 1 automatically each time a script is call and ignore the rest of numbers. The increments shall within this 4 digits (0001, ..., 0009,0010,...,0022, etc). Possible using sed/awk command to achieve the result?

Comment: Yes @userunknown!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To repeatedly increase the number, you have to protocoll it somewhere, for example in the file itself, or in a second file, in a database or whereever. We change the file itself, which is called inc.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
no=1

file="$1"
inc=$((no+1))
i=$(printf "%04d" $no)
o=$(printf "%04d" $inc)
sed -i "s/$i/$o/g" "$file"
sed -i "2s/$no/$inc/" ./inc.sh
```

You call it with `./inc.sh FILE` and in the end, it modifies itself. If you rename it, you have to change the 2nd sed command, which should in principle prefer an absolute filename.

Test, whether the target file, given as argument, exists and so on should be considered.

The counter has to stay in line 2, or the last sed call has to be adapted to the new position.

- In the beginning the number is 1.
- The argument to the script is a filename
- The increment is one bigger than no
- i for in shall be 4 places wide, filled with zeros
- o for out the same
- sed command to change all 0001 to 0002 in file
- sed command, to change line 2 from no to inc.

Comment: Thanks! This script could solve my problem statement here.